Is it a good idea to change transmission fluid?
I have a 200K 2008 HL. I don't know if the transmission fluid has been ever changed in this car.
Why I want to change it is because when I start the car and it's still cold, it's hard to change the gear shifter from P to others. And when I do it I feel like a kick/shock in car.
I think even if the car is warm it's not easy to change the gear from P to other options. I don't know if this is normal or there is an issue with the transmission and if changing the fluid or filter may help to resolve it?
PS: I don't like to make it worse either because it seems Toyota doesn't recommend to change the transmission fluid at all??

If your <I'm assuming Hilux> has a transmission dipstick, pull it out and smell it. Does it smell burnt? If so, it probably needs changed whether you wanted to or not.

Many manufacturers have 'lifetime fluids' in their transmissions, some manufacturers don't even have transmission dipsticks anymore (which makes them dipsticks in my estimation), so you have to get under the car if you want to check the level or condition of the fluid.
In practice these fluids don't always last the lifetime of the car, and should be changed if the condition of the fluid or symptoms suggest it needs to be done. The symptoms you describe sound are classic old fluid, so yes you should get a service for your transmission no matter what Toyota says.
